# dispaly all hierarchical post types from a taxonomy

Tags: loop, taxonomy

I have this loop and works fine, but the cpt Studio is hierarchical and I want to show in loop only first level of posts .. I can't find a solution...

```
<?php

$post_type = 'studio';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type


   $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );


foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :


// Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 box">

          <div class="inner-content">

    <?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug,

                )
            )

        );

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more about <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        <?php  echo get_the_title(); ?>
    </a>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

               </div>

         </div>



    <?php endforeach;

endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post_parent` arg to `WP_Query` can be set to 0 to only return top-level entries.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters